# Counting to now

Tags: code-challenge

**This is the goal:** count from 0 all the way to the current epoch time while the epoch time is still advancing in the fastest time possible. An example of how you'd do it could be as what is shown here in Python 2.7:

```
from time import time
start, end, count = None, None, 0
while count <= time():
    if start == None: start = time()
    count += 1
    end = time()
```

The above code took 10 minutes and 8 seconds to run through on an 8-core AMD with 16 GB of RAM. You must do it faster than that without skipping numbers and starting from zero.

## Scoring

Achieving a lower time than what Python did is the goal in addition to using the least amount of code too, but special attention will be given to the following:

- Code that takes the precise epoch time sourced from your counting to display something mentioning historical events or irrelevant ones that can be found on Wikipedia. (10 points)
- Getting the current epoch time from a source other than your own. (5 points)
- Your application continues to count alongside the epoch time after it catches up. (5 points)

50 points will be awarded to the person who achieves the lowest time and additional bonus points will be awarded from above if they're met.

## Deadline

The contest closes June 1st.

Comment: How much are the bonuses worth? You define them, but don't give them a value.

Comment: Added the scoring there for you. I had them earlier. :)

Comment: Your scoring is still completely arbitrary. How are time and code size factored into a single score, how much is a "point" worth?

Comment: So I suppose now the base score is code size in bytes (= points), and then -50 for the fastest and -10/5/5 for the bonuses? How can you possibly display historical events with 10 bytes of code? Regardless, the combination of multiple scoring criteria makes this a "code-challenge" and not "code-golf".

Comment: I've made the tag change there.

Comment: What is the purpose of `start` and `end` in your example? They don't *do* anything, and otherwise it's just a simple loop to a billion or so. Why does it take over 10 minutes to run?

Comment: The purpose of start and end was something I did due to it being in the interpreter and not standalone. It doesn't have any bearing on the overall speed. The use of the for loop is what makes it slow.

Comment: @Geobits I think the real "challenge" intended is to minimize the number of calls to `time()`, but personally I don't think it's gonna make much difference...

Answer (score 1):

## Java : 140

**No bonuses, ~60ms runtime**

Sets the start time in `j` and doesn't check time again until `j` is reached. Once it is, it keeps counting up to current time. Generally it only needs to check the time twice, since it runs in well under a second.

```
class N{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0,j=t();i++<j||i<t(););}static int t(){return (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);}}
```

Line breaks for clarity:

```
class N{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        for(int i=0,j=t();i++<j||i<t(););
    }
    static int t(){return (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, about 5 seconds

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
  time_t t=0, margin=0x40000000;
  int i;
  while (margin) {
    for (i=0;i<margin;i++) t++;
    while (margin && time(NULL)-t < margin) margin /= 2;
  }
  printf("t=%ld, time=%ld\n",t,time(NULL));
  return 0;
}
```